# Capture past goal visit information for an anonymous user in personalization

Tags: personalization, goals

I have senario in my project,where I need to personalize user journey.

On first visit user does some interaction in my site and trigger few goals and when he visits for the second time I need to personalize the same page based on the goals trigged by him on his first Visit.

The output which Iam getting,based on the current goal trigger the personalization is done not by the past goal trigger.

So far working:

On 2nd visit I am not able to get the goals triggered in the 1st visit ,so the personalization is not working.  The personalization is working based on the current goals trigger on the current visit only(for now on each visit i need to trigger the goal then only it works).

So far I tried.

1.Created Goa goal.

2.Added goal to target page that is to be personalized.

3.Added the rules.(refer the below screenshot)

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify and add more details about the output the user is getting?

Comment: Please provide more details with result?

Comment: On 2nd visit I am not able to get the goals triggered in the 1st visit ,so the personalization is not working.  The personalization is working based on the current goals trigger on the current visit only(for now on each visit i need to trigger the goal then only it works).

Comment: What version of sitecore

Comment: Can you try and just use the highlighted rule and make the else "hide" the component. I just created this rule in my QA environment and it works as expected. If this doesn't work in your environment, then we are looking at an issue with your environment. https://www.screencast.com/t/MUjPr03A3K39

Comment: Iam using 9.0 update 1 version but Iam using the same rule that you have used.Have you getting the goal that is triggered in the past visit or current visit?

Comment: Only after recycling of my instance in IIS,the personalization is woking as per the requirement